# mysql query returns only one results from my database

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in my database. Table users and table profile.

```
users(user_id, surname, email)
profile(profile_id, country, user_id)
```

user_id in table profile, is FK (comes from users table). I have the following query in order to select all surnames "smith" from my database, that are from country "USA". This is my query:

```
SELECT u.name, 
u.surname, 
u.email, 
u.user_id,
p.user_id
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN profile p ON p.country = 'USA'
WHERE u.surname = 'smith' AND u.user_id = p.user_id
```

this query works fine, but the problem is that returns only 1 result and not all results from my database (people with surname smith that are from USA). Any idea where it might be the wrong and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `u.user_id = p.user_id` condition with `ON condition` because you want to apply JOIN on 'user_id' field. And `where clause` should have the remaining condition.

```
SELECT u.name, 
       u.surname, 
       u.email, 
       u.user_id,
       p.user_id
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN profile p ON u.user_id = p.user_id
WHERE u.surname = 'smith' And p.country = 'USA'
```

You can read about [INNER JOINS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use only the columns in your `join on` condition that are relevant for the join. The columns that link 2 tables together. And put the rest in the `where` clause. That should work:

```
SELECT u.name, 
       u.surname, 
       u.email, 
       u.user_id,
       p.user_id
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN profile p ON u.user_id = p.user_id
WHERE p.country = 'USA'
AND u.surname = 'smith'
```

This is also better for readability. You can read it like this:

> SELECT these columns from table users. JOIN also table profile ON this 2 columns. After that filter the data and return only the records WHERE these conditions are met.